# MvvmCross pdb debug symbols not loading in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, mvvmcross, nuget-package, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I'm trying to load the symbol files that are included in the MvvmCross nuget package (while debugging a Xamarin.Android application on an Android 9 device (not an emulator)):

[image]

None of the above references seem to work, and so when I try to load them manually I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried it for every platform within the package's *lib* folder with no success (I'm targeting a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 running Android 9):

[image]

I've also tried setting up GitLink, but I don't have the MvvmCross project's repository checked-out into my project - I'm just simply trying to use the pre-compiled nuget package (update: [also works with GitHub or BitBucket urls so it does not require a local git repository to work](https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink/blob/develop/README.md)).

Does the pdb file need to be relocated to a specific folder within my project?

---

According to Process Monitor, the specific version of *MvvmCross.dll* being read is from the *monoandroid90* folder:

`.nuget\packages\mvvmcross\6.4.2\lib\monoandroid90\MvvmCross.dll`

and copied to:

`source\repos\TipCalc\TipCalc.Droid\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\MvvmCross.pdb`

Although I still get the same "matching symbol file not found" error when attempting to load it manually.

Comment: Try to empty symbol caches under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`Symbol` and then close VS Instance, delete bin, obj folder and then restart your project and test again.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT The symbol cache directory was already empty, however I did as suggested without success (nonetheless, good to know for future troubleshooting).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Upgrading/migrating machine, stay tuned... (and thanks)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Still upgrading (Dell and Microsoft have made it excruciatingly difficult)... I did manage to compile the mvvmcross repo and was just going to step through that, but will try this "black box" approach to symbol file consumption and report back after I'm up and running. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the progress about this issue.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I'm now dealing with a BIOS update that has prevented undervolting and reset values back to their factory defaults, which causes extreme overheating, and will not roll back or downgrade. Somehow the modification of processor core voltage is a security vulnerability, according to Intel.

Answer (score 0):

> Although I still get the same "matching symbol file not found" error
>   when attempting to load it manually.

You can try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**Suggestion**

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `.suo` file under `.vs` hidden folder of your solution folder.

**2)** Right-click on your project-->`Properties`-->`Build`-->`Advanced`-->change `Debugging information` to `Full`.

**3)** disable `Just My Code` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`

**4)** If these still do not work, please try to copy these related pdb files into the **OutPutpath** of the projects.

**5)** try to build your projects several times.

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all these suggestions without success. In my case it was related to a change in nuget packages. So, I did a rollback and the problem dissapeared.